# Is firebase functions.https.onCall a background function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am looking at rate limiting quotas on firebase for a singular busy function (called when logging in) and saw that there is a 1000 limit for background functions.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#additional_quotas_for_background_functions

I just want to check that functions.https.onCall is a https function and not a background function, thus not being limited. If 1000 people all load their data at one, I don't want it to fall over.

Comment: A callable function is exactly like an HTTPS function, except it does a few extra things for you automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in [Google Cloud Functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background). The definition is:

> You use background functions when you want to have your Cloud Function invoked indirectly in response to an event, such as a message on a Pub/Sub topic, a change in a Cloud Storage bucket, or a Firebase event.

This depends on your trigger. If you invoke your function via http call its not background function for sure.

I hope it will help!